# Python 3 "elif" not working

Tags: python

I'm new to Python 3 and I've got up to learning If Statements, however when I run the code it says "elif" is not recognized?

```
intE = 20

if intE < 20:
    print("Value is less than 20")
    elif intE > 20:
        print("Value is more than 20")
        else:
            print("Value is 20")
```

Comment: It's 'cause your indentation is wrong... `elif` should be in line with the `if` it's better to post the actual error.

Comment: Comes up with the error "Invalid Syntax" and highlights elif

Answer (score 4):

the problem is your indentation

```
intE = 20

if intE < 20:
    print("Value is less than 20")
elif intE > 20:
    print("Value is more than 20")
else:
    print("Value is 20")
```

Answer (score 1):

In python it's all about indents:) `if`, `elif` and `else` must be in same column:

```
intE = 20

if intE < 20:
    print("Value is less than 20")
elif intE > 20:
    print("Value is more than 20")
else:
    print("Value is 20")
```

Comment: Thankyou for all the help I'll remember that! sorry if it was a stupid question I'm new to coding i've only got a little experience with PhP, C# and C++

Answer (score 0):

In fact it should be:

```
intE = 20

if intE < 20:
    print("Value is less than 20")
elif intE > 20:
    print("Value is more than 20")
else:
    print("Value is 20")
```